# gettimeofday() not declared in this scope - Cygwin

Tags: c++, compilation, cygwin

Can cygwin make use of gettimeofday()? I'm getting the error:

```
lab8.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
lab8.cpp:62:30: error: ‘gettimeofday’ was not declared in this scope
     gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
                              ^
makefile:14: recipe for target 'lab8.o' failed
make: *** [lab8.o] Error 1
```

I definitely included `<sys/time.h>`. Is there a package that I have to install or does it just not work on Windows?

EDIT: Here's a simple test that yields the same error:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
    struct timeval start;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
}
```

With the error:

```
$ g++ -c -Wall -g -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test.o
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6:30: error: ‘gettimeofday’ was not declared in this scope
     gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define _BSD_SOURCE to include the declaration gettimeofday (since glibc2.2.2 according to link below)

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE

#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
    struct timeval start;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
}
```

[gettimeofday() - Unix, Linux System Call](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/settimeofday.htm)

Comment: Thanks this caught me after I did a "clean build" I had updated my cygwin install a few weeks ago and it didn't occur to me they may have changed such a basic function. of course he question now is why was it changed...

Comment: The linked article only says that `_BSD_SOURCE` is required for `settimeofday()`, not `gettimeofday()`. Can anyone confirm it is required for `gettimeofday()`, too?

Comment: It's not required for gettimeofday

Answer (score 3):

Thank you John - your question game me my answer!

In case it helps anyone else searching on this error...
I got the same error:

```
error: ‘gettimeofday’ was not declared in this scope
  gettimeofday(&lastBigTick, NULL);
```

This error started happening when I moved from Debian 8 (jessie) to Debian 9 (stretch) on a raspberry pi

For me, I had NOT #included "sys/time.h"  I had only #included "time.h"
Not sure how it compiled before, but it did, so adding

```
#include "sys/time.h"
```

did the job for me.

Note:  "time.h" is different and is still needed for other time functions, so I ended up needing both:

```
#include "time.h"
#include "sys/time.h"
```

My situation was perhaps different, as adding

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

made no difference in my case - ie this was not the issue for me.